# How to connect Mac Mini and Macbook through Universal Control when one is connected through ethernet and the other on Wifi?

Tags: network, wifi, mac-mini, universal-control

I used to connect both through Wifi, and it worked like a charm, but the Wifi was unstable on the Mac Mini. Now I connected the Mac Mini through ethernet but cannot combine both through Universal Control. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a definitive 'Ethernet is not allowed' but Apple does say Bluetooth & WiFi 'must be on'.
[Apple KB - Universal Control: Use a single keyboard and mouse between Mac and iPad](https://support.apple.com/HT212757)

It's quite possible to have simultaneous Ethernet & Wifi connections, just set Ethernet to be the Primary, in Network > Advanced…

[image]